# Does adding a key to authorized_keys make a 2 way ssh connection or only 1 way

Tags: ssh

If I add my public key to a servers `authorized_keys` file then I can ssh into the server with no password;

My question is, can the server ssh into my machine with no password too? or I have to add the servers pub key to my file for that to also happen?

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd have to add a public key your machines authorized_keys file for the server to ssh into your machine.  Even then another user on the server would  need your corresponding private key to do so.